# Does female need to make up her menstruation fasts?

Tags: hadith, sawm, menses

Salam I am looking for hadiths that say a female has to make up for her missed fasts if she menstruates during Ramadan. I could not find it in the Quran.

Answer (score 4):

Hadith from Sahih Muslim

> Mu'adha said: I asked 'A'isha: What is the reason that a menstruating woman completes the fasts (that she abandons during her monthly course). but she does not complete the prayers? She (Hadrat 'A'isha) said: Are you a Haruriya? I said: I am not a Haruriya, but I simply want to inquire. She said: We passed through this (period of menstruation), and **we were ordered to complete the fasts, but were not ordered to complete the prayers**. - [Sahih Muslim Book 3 Hadith 662](http://muflihun.com/muslim/3/662)

Jazakummullahu khairan
Wassalām warahmatullāhi wa barakātuhu

Answer (score -4):

In Surah Al-Bagharh Ayah 184&185:

> [Fasting for] a limited number of days. So whoever among you is ill or
> on a journey [during them] - then an equal number of days [are to be
> made up]. And upon those who are able [to fast, but with hardship] - a
> ransom [as substitute] of feeding a poor person [each day]. And
> whoever volunteers excess - it is better for him. But to fast is best
> for you, if you only knew. (184)
>
> The month of Ramadhan [is that] in
> which was revealed the Qur'an, a guidance for the people and clear
> proofs of guidance and criterion. So whoever sights [the new moon of]
> the month, let him fast it; and whoever is ill or on a journey - then
> an equal number of other days. Allah intends for you ease and does not
> intend for you hardship and [wants] for you to complete the period and
> to glorify Allah for that [to] which He has guided you; and perhaps
> you will be grateful. (185)

As menstruates is a kind of illness, so this ayat explains what women should do.

Comment: menstruates is a kind of illness?

Comment: isn't it a kind of illness? Don't women need to rest in those days?In those days, Which woman can say she is as productive as other days? For your reference, Ulama use these two Ayahs to prove this Fatwa. It's your choice to not accept this Ayah